# MongoCursorTimeoutException in jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I have a query which looks up data in a huge collection (over 48M), yet even if I add `timeout=-1` to it, it still throws `MongoCursorTimeoutException` exception..

```
return \DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('stats')->timeout(-1)
    ->where('ip','=',$alias)
    ->where('created_at','>=', new \DateTime( $date ) )
    ->where('created_at','<=', new \DateTime( $date . ' 23:59:59' ) )
    ->count();
```

I am using this library: `https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`

Any ideas?

Comment: 48M isn't too big. Do you have an index on `ip` and `created_at`? (I know nothing of laravel, so I can't help you with the timeout exception trigger...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue [PHP-1249 - MongoCursor::count() should use cursor's socket timeout](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1249) submitted for PHP MongoDB driver v1.5.7 which was fixed in v1.5.8 in October, 2014.

The [reply](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1249?focusedCommentId=744139&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-744139) from the support:

> Looking into the code a bit, it appears that both socket timeout and `maxTimeMS` is not passed along to the `count` command.
>
> If you need an immediate work-around, you should be able to get by with `MongoDB::command()` for now (which can support both timeouts).

The workaround posted by one of the users is:

```
$countComand = $mongo->command(
    array(
        'count' => 'collection',
        'query' => $query
    ),
    array('socketTimeoutMS' => -1)
);

 
if($countComand['ok']){
    $count = $countComand['n'];
} else {
    // ... error ...
}
```

It seems that [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) doesn't use `MongoDB::command()`. You either have to write your query explicitly without help of `where` methods as shown above or upgrade to v.1.5.8.